# custom knockout binding in object literal

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

how can i implement multiple custom knockout bindings that can be declared in an object literal?

basically instead of doing this:

```
 <input data-bind="customBinding1:observable1, customBinding2: observable2 }" />
```

I would like to be able to do this:

```
<input data-bind="customBinding0: { customBinding1: observable1, customBinding2: observable2 }" />
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You cant customBinding0 will be the only binding handler, it will how ever get a object literal as valueAccesor containng the data

Comment: @Anders seen it on knockout-kendo.js as `<input data-bind="kendoAutoComplete: { data: choices, value: selectedChoice }" />` where `choices` and `selectedChoice` can both be observables.

Comment: What you saw in kendo is a single binding, `kendoAutoComplete`, that take a single object literal as its binding value.  This object literal supports two `observable` settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Knockout, bindings are specified in name/value pairs, where `name` is the name of the binding, and `value` is the value that will be retrieved within the binding using `valueAccessor()`.

It sounds like you may be wanting to pass multiple values in to a binding, like your kendo example shows.  Although each binding can only have a single value, that value can be anything.  This means you can pass in an object literal as the value, and the object can have as many properties as you want.  These properties can also be of any type that you want - you'll just need to handle them correctly inside your binding.

Here's a simple example:

**View**

```
<div data-bind="myBinding: {setting1: viewModelProperty1, 
                            setting2, viewModelProperty2}"></div>
```

**Binding**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor() || {};

        //this gives you the value of setting1
        var setting1 = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.setting1);

       //if you need to do something just when `setting1` changes,
       //  add a subscription to the value like so:
       if( ko.isObservable(options.setting1) ){
           options.setting1.subscribe(function(newValue){
              //do something because the setting1 value changed
           });
       }
    }
};
```

You also have the option of specifying multiple bindings, each with its own value, and referencing the additional bindings and values from within the first one.  Knockout's `options` and `optionsText` bindings are an example of this approach.

**Excellent Resource:**  http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html

Take some time to study and experiment with the examples at the link above.  There's a lot of good information here that covers what you need to do.

Comment: `//if you need to do something just when setting1 changes,
//  add a subscription to the value like so:`
thats exactly what i couldn't think of. thanks for answer, much apriciated.

Comment: You can also add an `update: ` section to the binding, along with `init: `.  the update function will execute when **any** observable in the object literal changes, but it's difficult to determine which setting changed.  Of course you can reapply all the settings, but for complex bindings with many settings, this is unfeasible.